# When a static method is called from multiple source

Tags: java, c#, .net

Lets say i have a static method with parameter in a class as shown :

```
 public static string NumberToLetter(int num)
{
    string colCharset = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    string Letter = String.Empty;
    //goes into loop using the parameter
    //does some logic
    return Letter;
}
```

Now what happens when this static method is called from other classes at a same time ?

Or in such a manner that when the first class called this method and starts executing and another class calls this static method when it is executing the first class request ?

What will be the behavior ? What will happen to the parameter value which is in loop?

Comment: do you know what a race-condition is and how to avoid it?

Comment: what is the relevance of the ***int num*** btw?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ it is used inside loop

Comment: The local variables belong to the method call—each call of the method has its own version of the internal variables.

Comment: @khelwood that means every time this method is called the parameter value is set fixed for each caller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is static, your local variable is not. If there are no dependencies to outside static resources then it should work just fine.

If would be totally different issue if you would be passing in a reference parameter or a mutable object.

Comment: I think the parameter value will be changed when called by second caller.

Comment: @SangitGurung it's not. The methods are executed [in separate activation frames](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.5).

Answer (score 7):

The variables in this static method are local, so they will be created for each call. You will have n copies of these variables for n calls. Your parameter is not a reference type, so your parameter is also not shared.

Unless you share a variable/property/field in a method, multiple calls are thread safe, if that is what you mean.